# How to read data from api using retrofit in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

Below is my json and I am trying to read data under the "productsDetalys" using retrofit.

I can read the data like "orders_id", "customers_id" etc but "productsDetalys" returns null.

```
{
  "body": [
    {
      "orders_id": "52",
      "customers_id": "1",
      "customers_name": "Nida Verkkopalvelu",
      "customers_company": "Etäisyys 2.3 km",
      "customers_street_address": "Suoratie 40",
      "customers_suburb": "",
      "customers_city": "Porvoo",
      "customers_postcode": "06100",
      "customers_state": "",
      "customers_country": "Finland",
      "customers_telephone": "09444744",
      "customers_email_address": "test@nida.fi",
      "delivery_name": "Nida Verkkopalvelu",
      "delivery_company": "Etäisyys 2.3 km",
      "delivery_street_address": "Suoratie 40",
      "delivery_suburb": "",
      "delivery_city": "Porvoo",
      "delivery_postcode": "06100",
      "delivery_state": "",
      "delivery_country": "Finland",
      "payment_method": "Paytrail - Online Payment",
      "payment_module_code": "paytrail",
      "shipping_method": "Per Item (Best Way)",
      "shipping_module_code": "item",
      "coupon_code": "",
      "date_purchased": "2023-04-10 10:01:49",
      "orders_status": "2",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "currency_value": "1.000000",
      "order_total": "55.00",
      "order_tax": "0.00",
      "language_code": "en",
      "comments": "",
      "productsDetalys": [
        [
          {
            "orders_products_id": "111",
            "products_name": "Book",
            "products_price": "0.00",
            "final_price": "52.50",
            "products_tax": "0.00",
            "products_quantity": 1,
            "products_options": "Version",
            "products_options_values": "Book Hard Cover",
            "options_values_price": "52.50"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "itemCount": 1
}
```

here is my model classes;

OrderDetailsModelClass;

```
data class OrderDetailsModelClass(
    val body: List<BodyOrderDetails>,
    val itemCount: Int
)
```

BodyOrderDetails

```
data class BodyOrderDetails(
    val comments: String,
    val coupon_code: String,
    val currency: String,
    val currency_value: String,
    val customers_city: String,
    val customers_company: String,
    val customers_country: String,
    val customers_email_address: String,
    val customers_id: String,
    val customers_name: String,
    val customers_postcode: String,
    val customers_state: String,
    val customers_street_address: String,
    val customers_suburb: String,
    val customers_telephone: String,
    val date_purchased: String,
    val delivery_city: String,
    val delivery_company: String,
    val delivery_country: String,
    val delivery_name: String,
    val delivery_postcode: String,
    val delivery_state: String,
    val delivery_street_address: String,
    val delivery_suburb: String,
    val language_code: String,
    val order_tax: String,
    val order_total: String,
    val orders_id: String,
    val orders_status: String,
    val payment_method: String,
    val payment_module_code: String,
    val ProductsDetalys: List<List<ProductsDetalys>>,
    val shipping_method: String,
    val shipping_module_code: String
)
```

ProductsDetalys

```
data class ProductsDetalys(
    val final_price: String,
    val options_values_price: String,
    val orders_products_id: String,
    val products_name: String,
    val products_options: String,
    val products_options_values: String,
    val products_price: String,
    val products_quantity: Int,
    val products_tax: String
)
```

This is my API interface for retrofit

```
interface ProductDetailsApi {
    @GET()
    fun getProductDetails() : Call<OrderDetailsModelClass>
}
```

And MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   lateinit var orderDetailsList: List<BodyOrderDetails>
   lateinit var productsDetailsList: List<ProductsDetalys>

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_details)

        val retrofitProductDetails = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://pizzapalvelu.fi/158a/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()

        val apiProductDetailsList = retrofitProductDetails.create(ProductDetailsApi::class.java)

        apiProductDetailsList.getProductDetails().enqueue(object :
            Callback<OrderDetailsModelClass> {

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<OrderDetailsModelClass>,
                response: Response<OrderDetailsModelClass>
            ) {
                
                orderDetailsList = response.body()?.body ?: orderDetailsList
                //In this part, I can read data. But When I Log the orderDetailsList,
                //productsDetalys comes null.

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<OrderDetailsModelClass>, t: Throwable) {
                t.message?.let { Log.e("mesaj", it) }
            }
        })

   }
}
```

What should I do? Where am I wrong?
Thanks for advance for your replies?

Comment: In ```BodyOrderDetails``` class , can you change from ```ProductsDetalys``` to ```productsDetalys ``` and try again to read?

Comment: Sure an issue in key name, Use this plugin to avoid such issues and save time. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-